# Populate multiple select field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I try to populate a multiple select field in laravel like this:

```
{{ Form::select('maisons[]', $maisons, $partenaire->maisons->pluck('id'), ['class' => '', 'multiple' ]) }}
```

The option are not select in the dropdown.
I then tried this:

```
$partenaire->maisons->pluck('id')
```

and it returns an array: [1,2,3] (example)

I then tried to put the array manually in the field like this:

```
{{ Form::select('maisons[]', [1,2,3], ['class' => '', 'multiple' ]) }}
```

The previous line returns the select field with the select iptions.

What is wrong then ?

More information, here is dd($partenaire->maisons->pluck('id'))

```
Collection {#671 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => 3
    1 => 8
    2 => 12
    3 => 13
    4 => 17
    5 => 21
  ]
}
```

and dd($maisons)

```
Collection {#378 ▼
  #items: array:300 [▼
    1 => "Test 1"
    2 => "Test 2"
    3 => "Test 3"
    4 => "Test 4"
    5 => "Test 5"
    6 => "Test 6"
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Laravel version 5.3 => ...

```
pluck()
```

returns a collection and therefore you need to append `toArray()` at the end like this:

```
$partenaire->maisons->pluck('id')->toArray()
```

and that should return you the options in your select box!

Comment: Oh, that's it! Thank you